Is it possible to create a reference line or band that only shows under certain conditions in Google Data Studio?
I have a bar graph with air quality data, and I would like to add reference lines or bands for various air quality levels (for ex. unhealthy at 55, very unhealthy at 125 etc.). However, my current data is low (under 10) and the bars are extremely small because it automatically shows all of the reference lines. Is there a way to make it so that a reference line or band will only show up if the data exceeds a certain amount?
